# How do I bundle log-lines by request in Kibana?

Tags: logging, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

In Stackdriver Log Viewer (for our Google AppEngine app),  lines from a single HTTP-request follow each other sequentially, rather than being mixed into lines from other requests. Also, they are bundled in a  visually-distinguished, foldable section. See image below.

This is very useful in tracking behavior inside a single HTTP request.

How do we do this in Elastic Stack? (Each log-line does have  a `request_id` field.)

[image]

Comment: would you be able to show us an example please?

Comment: See image from Stackdriver

Comment: There's the [aggregate filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html), which should be able to do it. But I've never used it and I'm too lazy to try. Also you should provide log lines, so if someone wants to try, they'll have test cases.

Comment: The image site is throwing a certificate error. You should try to add the image in the post.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It is not clear. You already have a requestId field, so you can query logs of a particular request. What is the issue?

Comment: @harogaston Close, but we don't want to query logs of one particular request. We want "GROUP BY"-like functionality so that the log viewer one  request after the other  in time order,  rather than one log-line after the other in time order. See  screenshot.

Comment: What does this has to do with Kibana? I though that was a Kibana screenshot but it is not.

Comment: That is a Stackdriver Log Viewer screenshot (note the first line of the question text.)

Comment: The question is now to do, in Elastic Stack, what we already  do in Stackdriver.